# Length matching, Routed or Signal on Altium?

Tags: altium, length-matching

I have searched some information about the diference between Signals and Routed on the PCB Tab in Altium, and I understand it, but, when you have to do a length matching, Which is the best option? The diference is not stable (2 mils, 3 mils, it depends of the trace I have done).

Thank you so much!

Edit adding an example with huge difference between routed an signal.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand that 30 mils difference.

EDIT 2: Checking the vias, there is a lot of length trace on them, and invisible traces. That was the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use Signal Length but that only works between 2 pads. If you use routed length you will need to make sure there are no unneeded "hidden" bits of trace in the pads because these trace segments will be counted in the final routed length. Altium will sometimes terminate traces incorrectly based on the settings you currently have applied. If you visually inspect a selected trace you can see if the trace has properly terminated at the pad and then the Routed Length will be somewhat accurate.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have realized that there is a huge difference on my case between two lines, but there are the same number of vias, I don't understand the difference, Is the difference because the accordions that make longer the trace but not the signal?

Thank you so much!